# incompatible types : object cannot be converted to ChatData

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to JAVA and was trying to exchange the objects between the client and server using readObject() but it was showing `incompatible types : object cannot be converted to ChatData` . Why did the error occurred and how to resolve this. Please tell me how it works.

```
  ` Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
    ObjectOutputStream clientWriter;
    ObjectInputStream clientReader;
    try {
        clientWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        clientReader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        ChatData clientOutputData = new ChatData("Hello! This is a message from the client number ", socket.getInetAddress());
        clientWriter.writeObject(clientOutputData);

        ChatData clientInputData = clientReader.readObject(); //Here is the error and the ChatData is another class.

        try {
            // do processing
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (clientReader != null) {
                clientReader.close();
            }
            if (clientWriter != null) {
                clientWriter.close();
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't close the connection succesfully");
            Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    }
 }
```

Comment: does casting it to `ChatData` work ? `ChatData clientInputData = (ChatData)clientReader.readObject();`

Comment: Yes, it did work. But why is it that necessary to cast it?

Comment: because java is a static, strong typed programming language, so implicit casting (what you were doing) is a big no no for the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

[readObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29) method returns an Object of type **object**.

You have to convert the received object to the type you want.

```
ChatData clientInputData = clientReader.readObject(); //Here is the error and the ChatData is another class.
```

Solution:

```
ChatData clientInputData = (ChatData) clientReader.readObject();
```

You should also check if the received object is of that type you want, otherwise a ClassCastException could be thrown.

```
Object clientInputData = clientReader.readObject();
ChatData convertedChatData = null;
if(clientInputData instanceof ChatData) {
    convertedChatData = (ChatData) clientInputData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the result of `readObject()` to the needed class *explicitly* since the return type of [readObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29) is `Object`:

```
ChatData clientInputData = (ChatData) clientReader.readObject();
```

Also you can wrap it into `try-catch` block, in such a case you'll be able to handle `ClassCastException` error:

```
try {
    ChatData clientInputData = (ChatData) clientReader.readObject();
} catch (ClassCastException e){
    //handle error
}
```

And one more advice: use IDE such an Intellij IDEA or Eclipse, they will warn you about that before compilation.